# Redis SortSet Score And Rank

Tags: redis

I want to use redis sortset to achieve leaderboards.
I want the user who has the same point has the same rank. 
But I found that the sortset is ordered by dictionary when the score is the same.
How can I achieve it？

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227796/redis-sortedset-how-to-get-values-in-numerical-order-rather-than-alphabetical-o?rq=1

Comment: thanks.I want to achieve this case:when the score is same,then their rank is same.Please.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem I linked :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis SortedSet: How to get values in numerical order rather than alphabetical order when two values has the same score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227796/redis-sortedset-how-to-get-values-in-numerical-order-rather-than-alphabetical-o)

Comment: That's the one I posted @sazzad ;)

Comment: @trevorj I did not comment, but flagged this question. That comment is auto generated :P